# cannot see any elements rendered with Three js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

This is the Three.js (`main.js`) code:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: document.querySelector('#bg') });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);

   cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
   cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

   renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

This is the `Index.html` section:

```html
<section class="hero">
   <span id="element" data-aos="fade-down"></span>
   <div id="bg"></div>
</section>
```

After running `npx vite`, I don't see any elements rendered on the page. Please help me; I am learning Three.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation of [WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer):

> `canvas` - A canvas where the renderer draws its output.

So the element with the id "bg" needs to be a *canvas*, but not a *div*:

<s>`<div id="bg"></div>`</s>

```html
<canvas id="bg"></canvas>
```

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: document.querySelector('#bg') });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);

   cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
   cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

   renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.153/build/three.js"></script>
<section class="hero">
   <span id="element" data-aos="fade-down"></span>
   <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
</section>
```